# Positive definiteness of Hessians?

Tags: optimization, convex, hessian

I'm reading the book "[Convex Optimization](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)" by Boyd and Vandenbherge. On the second paragraph of page 71, the authors seem to state that in order to check if the Hessian (H) is positve semidefinite (for a function f in R), this reduces to the second derivative of the function being positive for any x in the domain of f and for the domain of f to be an interval. However, am I right to assume that the case for R^n is more complex, that is, I need to do more work to proof that z^THz is positive for any z (likely using minors, or something else)?

Comment: The previous paragraph provides the result relating convexity to positive definiteness of the Hessian for $R^n$.  Characterizations of a matrix being positive semidefinite are provided elsewhere in the book. In other words, the point of the 2nd paragraph is to show how things simplify in one dimension.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this makes sense. Could you also elaborate on where do they give more details on the characterization of a matrix being positive semidefinite? I'm particularly interested in studying the loss functions of neural network-like models (I know they're usually non-convex). Cheers.

Comment: You can look at Appendix A, and also search "positive definite" and "positive semidefinite" in the pdf. A lot of the material is somewhat advanced and assumes you already have a basic background, for which you should perhaps look at standard texts on linear algebra, and then come back to this book after you have studied the basics of positive definiteness and eigenvalues, for instance.  Also some "math analysis".